# Where does Firefox (Snap) store the profiles?

Tags: firefox, snap, directory, configuration

There's no `~/.mozilla/firefox`, only `~/snap/firefox/` but that does not seem to have the profiles:

<s>`~/snap/firefox$ find places.sqlite`

`find: ‘places.sqlite’: No such file or directory`</s>

Not sure what this translates to:

```
$ snap connections firefox
Interface                 Plug                            Slot                             Notes
...

personal-files            firefox:dot-mozilla-firefox     :personal-files                  -
```

---

Edit:

`find` doesn't work as simple, instead use:

```
~/snap/firefox$ find . -name places.sqlite 
./common/.mozilla/firefox/<ID>.default/places.sqlite
```

Comment: for whatever incredible reason, `~/.mozilla/firefox` still exists for me, and it is this directory that firefox will use, if I run `/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I upgraded to 22.04 yesterday and Firefox has imported my profiles from the original directory inside `~/.mozilla/firefox/` into the new directory of `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/` this is where they are stored now.

If you navigate to `about:profiles` it will show your current profile and it's full path.

The personal-files socket grants access to $HOME, see more info [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/the-personal-files-interface/9357)

Answer (score 7):

It is stored in

```
~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox
```

Comment: Thanks, also just found out looking at `about:profiles` (regular settings don't show any paths).