# trying to install geckodriver breaks firefox... and snap? What the

Tags: firefox, snap

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on my laptop and have been, for a while, leaning away from using snap. Now I am leaning away from using firefox.

I tried to get geckodriver installed in order to run python-selenium scrapes. I was not successful.

But, since something expected the geckodriver executable to be in /snap/bin and some of these things are soft linked to each other, I now get this:

```
 $ snap
 WebDriver implementation for Firefox
 
 Usage: 
 
 Options:
       --allow-hosts <ALLOW_HOSTS>...
 ...
```

I get the same thing from trying to launch firefox on the command-line as well. They are obviously pointing to a geckodriver executable and the snap and the firefox executables have perhaps been deleted?

I am now using Brave but I would like to be able to use firefox at times. And I do not want to delete or lose all of my history, bookmarks and profiles.

But how can I do a "snap-ish" install of firefox if breaking firefox has also broken snap? And why was it so easy to paint myself into this corner?

Comment: Try backing up the bookmarks etc (with Firefox sync) and then use the APT (non-snap) version of Firefox https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: it is a bit hard to back up the bookmarks with Firefox sync if firefox is not launchable. Unless there is another way of doing this? Another problem is that no snap command is executable. So using snap to do something does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually copy the snap Firefox [profile](https://askubuntu.com/a/1414759/124466) and restore bookmarks/history [manually](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile) after [installing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401) Firefox APT version.