# Firefox won't start after updating. How to restore the previous version without losing profile data?

Tags: software-installation, updates, firefox, restore, downgrade

Firefox won't start after updating to version 123.0.

At the same time, no errors will appear, and there is also no specific crash report that would help understand the reason.

How to restore the previous version without losing profile data?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1414757/1004020 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1198022/1004020

Comment: I try to use: $ snap list firefox --all, it gives me an error: no matching snaps installed

Comment: If you used the third-party non-snap Firefox PPA, that's not as supported as the snap. Try https://askubuntu.com/a/138327/1004020

Comment: I was able to restore the previous version from the tar bz archive that I saved

Comment: @DanielT, thanks for your help

Comment: On Ubuntu, we usually don't use "the tar bz archive". It is not recommended to install software like that, and that might have caused the "won't start after updating"

Comment: @DanielT, previously, Firefox worked stably, only the latest automatic update led to unstable work...

Comment: If you are using https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux and selecting the "Install Firefox from Mozilla builds", then that's not the recommended way on Ubuntu. We only support "Install from your distribution package manager (Recommended)". You shouldn't see any popup for "the latest automatic update" because apt/snap should be doing it

Comment: @DanielT, thank you. I need to learn how to use the distribution package manager correctly. This will be very useful in the future...